How to write to multiple excel files using pd.ExcelWriter based on different conditions
I've used pd.ExcelWriter before, and I was successfully able to write to multiple Excel worksheets within a single Excel file. Now, I am trying to write to a single worksheet within multiple excel files. One issue I'm having, however, to determine what file pd.ExcelWriter should write to, the function will need to be placed in a loop. This causes the function to repeatedly write the same thing again and again based on the conditional loop, and may sometimes fail to reach the other logic to write to the other excel files in the directory. I can't think of any other way to determine what file to write to and then proceed with the ExcelWriter function. Here is the relevant code:
# Iterate through the time periods
for period_name, period in time_periods.items():
    target_file = get_target_file(period_name)
    if target_file:
        file_path_out = os.path.join(output_directory, target_file)
        # Initialize pd.ExcelWriter for the current target file
        with pd.ExcelWriter(file_path_out, mode='a', engine='openpyxl', if_sheet_exists='overlay') as writer:
            for key, fin_data in fin_data_dict.items():
                period, approach = key
            ###Further logic to determine where and with what data to write in the respective excel file(s)###

Any assistance or tips will be much appreciated. Thanks!

I am afraid you will have to move writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_path_out) inside the forloop.

If files don't exist, you will have to use xlsxwriter as the engine: writer = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_path, engine='xlsxwriter')

@rachel As a general comment; If the files dont exist you can still use Openpyxl as the engine, just use mode='w' and the file will be created. So you can change the mode to suit based on the existance of the Excel file (noting that if_sheet_exists= would need to change as well).

@rachel, So do I really not have any recourse? The files do exist, I don't intend on creating any new files.

I am not quite sure what your fin_data_dict looks like, but below code works for me:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

output_directory = ''
fin_data_dict = {('period1', 'approach1'): np.random.uniform(low=-10, high=10, size=400),
                 ('period1', 'approach2'): np.random.uniform(low=-10, high=10, size=200),
                 ('period2', 'approach1'): np.random.uniform(low=-5, high=5, size=200)}

for (period, approach), fin_data in fin_data_dict.items():
    target_file = f'{period}.xlsx'
    file_path_out = os.path.join(output_directory, target_file)
    with pd.ExcelWriter(file_path_out, mode='a', engine='openpyxl', if_sheet_exists='overlay') as writer:
        data_df = pd.DataFrame(fin_data, columns=['data_column'])
        data_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=approach)


My apologies for not clarifying further. fin_data_dict is a dictionary containing all my dataframes/ datasets that are organized by their respective time period and location. get_target_file is a custom function that determines what excel file the code should write to based on the different time periods in another dictionary. I can add this function to my post if you'd like a closer look. I think your code follows the same logic as mine, but my code just fails to write to other excel files in my directory.

@Ace_1918, the logic is not exactly the same, I removed your outer for loop for period_name, period in time_periods.items(), and moved with pd.ExcelWriter() inside your inner for loop for key, fin_data in fin_data_dict.items(). but that might not be what you want. so I will need more clarification from you: 1. What is exactly the relationship between time_periods and fin_data_dict? 2. Is it possible to add some sample data for both time_periods and fin_data_dict? 3. I doubt that the culprit is get_target_file, but it wouldn't hurt if you add that in your original post too.
